# How to add the user's username / ID to the URL after successful logon?

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my web application I want the page URL to point to current user by his username/ID

so when i change the username the browser moves me to the other username page.

for example like this: www.XYZcom/Member.aspx?userID="012345"

i want to do this because i have a search method and when i click on the resulted hyperlinks, the link returns me back to my own profile, not the username i clicked on.

I'm using c# and ASP.NET.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Is this ASP .NET MVC?  If so you should look up routing and global.asax.

Comment: In addition to @PeteGO 's comment above. If you are in fact using MVC then you can add the user id value to the view bag, add it as an optional parameter on the route, save the id to the authentication cookie during login, or if you are assuming that your users will have cookies enabled then you can always create a cookie to house the user id so that you can access the user id from anywhere without having to ensure that it is passed with the route/querystring. Although assuming that your users will enable cookies is generally not a good practice.

Comment: I don't know what MVC is, i using visual stodio professional 2010 with asp.net and c# for code behind files.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Add()
```

include System.Data in your file and use HttpContext to get and set parameters to the url.

You said that you are using c# so this is an example of using C# in the code behind file or controller. You can also accomplish this on the client using java script, but I will wait for a response from you in regards to where you are trying to append to the url.

Comment: I never used JavaScript, i prefer to do this task in global.asax file if possible, or just write it in the code behind with c#

Comment: I succeeded in changing the browser url and appended the username, but the profile page didnt change it still my profile page!                       code from hyperlink:                                                     <asp:HyperLink ID="UsernameLink" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("username") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("username", "~/profile.aspx?username={0}") %>'> </asp:HyperLink>                                         please help ):

Comment: My guess would be that you are trying to evaluate the username value, but it is unable to acquire that value because it doesn't exist. I am assuming that you are trying to use the username value from the query string. I need more insight into your problem. The page should not change because you add a userid value to the query string. Rather it does give you access to value like user id/name and you can use that value to display content within the page. what is your end goal?

Comment: i already have the usernames i want form repeatercontrol in search method.

Comment: i want the user to redirected to the profile of the username shown the hyperlink, now it just takes me back to my profile not the username i click on.

Comment: @user1867815 You are going to need to build some logic into the profile page that on load will determine whether a userid has been provided via the query string and if so will gather what it needs from a datasource to populate the fields of the profile page. Adding userid to the query string doesnt give it instructions of what to do.  Example: I have a login screen - user logs in and I assign their userid to the query string. Redirect to profile page with userid in query string. Have some logic in profile page to gather my profile information and fill the form.